# Recursion function to calculate factorial not working properly for larger numbers

Tags: julia

I am taking a course in data-structures and trying to replicate the same in Julia.

I am using the below code in Julia -

```
function factorial(n)
    if n <= 1
        return 1
    else
        return n*factorial(n-1)
    end
end
```

It is working fine with number less than or equal to 20, but for 21 and greater I am getting negative value. Same logic is working fine in Python, below is the code -

```
def factorial(n):
    assert n >= 0 and int(n) == n, 'The number must be positive integer only'
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)
```

can you pleas help me understand what might be the problem?

Comment: I don't know Julia as well as some other languages, but what you're probably seeing is integer overflow due to Julia using a fixed number of bits.  Once you overflow, you trigger the sign bit so the result will look like negative garbage.  Python, on the other hand, has arbitrary sized integers and flips over to use those automagically when the results get big enough.  (I just did a quick experiment, and 21! pushes you over 2^63 so Julia is probably using 64-bit signed integers)

Answer (score 2):

As 张实唯 mentioned in the comments, you could pass in a BigInt as an input to calculate larger numbers.

To keep your code type stable, return `one(n)` instead of `1`. This will make sure that whatever type was sent as input will be returned, keeping your code type stable.

```
julia> function factorial(n)
           if n <= 1
               return one(n)
           else
               return factorial(n - 1) * n
           end
       end
factorial (generic function with 1 method)
```

### Outputs

```
julia> typeof(factorial(10))
Int64

julia> typeof(factorial(BigInt(10)))
BigInt

julia> typeof(factorial(big"100"))
BigInt

julia> factorial(big"100")
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

### Alternative one-liner

You could also write the above function as a line-liner, using [Julia's ternary operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#?:).

```
factorial(n) = n <= 1 ? one(n) : factorial(n-1) * n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Niczky - I am new to Julia programming can you please point me to the topics which can explain the following - the one liner you used - Like the code does not look very intutive with '?' and regarding assignment of variable values to the function - I would like to read a bit more on that so that I can understand it better. Thanks again

Comment: They are called ternary operators. I amended my answer to include a link to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Overflow-behavior):

> In Julia, exceeding the maximum representable value of a given type results in a wraparound behavior

And the range for `Int64` type (used by default on 64-bit machines to store integers) is:

```
julia> typemin(Int64)
-9223372036854775808

julia> typemax(Int64)
9223372036854775807
```

Instead use `BigInt` that implements arbitrary precision integers. You can convert any integer into `BigInt` using the `big` function. The downside of this approach is that the function will be slower:

```
function factorial(n)
    if n <= 1
        return big(1)
    else
        return big(n) * factorial(n-1)
    end
end
```

And now you have:

```
julia> factorial(21)
51090942171709440000

julia> factorial(100)
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

#### EDIT

The example showing that the code of OP is not type stable:

```
julia> using Test

julia> function factorial(n)
           if n <= 1
               return 1
           else
               return n*factorial(n-1)
           end
       end
factorial (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @inferred factorial(big"21")
ERROR: return type BigInt does not match inferred return type Union{Int64, BigInt}
```

Comment: Alternatively you can input a BigInt with the function definition untouched. `factorial(big"21")` works well with the original function.

Comment: What 张实唯 proposes would work, but then it would not be type stable (as it would return either `Int` or `BigInt` depending on `n`). In general probably it would be good to add `n::Integer` in the signature to restrict arguments to be integers as this is something you probably want ensured.

Comment: Actually it is type stable. Type stability means the type of local variables and output can be infered from the types, rather than values, of the arguments. The arguments being Any (which is the default if you don't specify) does not imply type instability: Julia will compile multiple versions of the function, each specialized to a combination of argument types.

Comment: Ok, I didn't spot the literal `1`. Yes, it need to change to `one(n)` to be type stable.